# Visual Studio hangs and crashes on build error

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, compilation, visual-studio-2017

A few days ago Visual Studio 2015 started dying on me when compiling.
If the build is successful it takes forever to compile and Visual Studio hangs.
If the build fails Visual Studio kindly hangs and then I get a message saying the program has stopped:

[image: Death message]

This has never happened before and my work has been blocked for 3 days now.
I'm desperate. Any ideas?

Things I've tried:

- Restart my computer (still dies)
- Restart Visual Studio (still dies)
- Build another project (still dies)
- Deleting the .suo file in the solution (still dies)
- Disabling ReSharper (still dies)
- Removing ReSharper (still dies)
- Resetting Visual Studio to its default settings (still dies)
- Uninstalled and reinstalled Visual Studio 2015 (still dies)
- Uninstalled and installed Visual Studio 2017 (still dies)
- Run a memory check (Memory is OK. VS dies.)
- Combining one or more of the above solutions (dies...)
- Other teammates don't experience the problem. Same tools same projects.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit 1:**

- Tried with a new, untouched, project as suggested by @Surreal.
  Compiles successfully. I break the code on purpose and VS dies.
- Tried manually running MSBuild on my solution from the command-line as suggested by @bsinky. Build fails with a strange error.
  What is this "target go" thing? I looked it up on Google and can't seem to find anything related.

  [image: Build result]

Comment: I would assume it dies when you file -> new project and compile that as well correct?

Comment: I don't have a solid answer, but you could try invoking "msbuild MyProject.proj /t:go /fl /flp:logfile=MyProjectOutput.log;verbosity=diagnostic " yourself to compile your solution from the command line, this would let you capture a build log.  For reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171470.aspx

Comment: @Surreal, yes. A new project also dies on build error.

Comment: @bsinky, added the results of the build verbose to the original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No idea how this was related but cleaning my Windows' temp folder along with the prefetch folder fixed the problem (I used [CCleaner](https://www.piriform.com/ccleaner/download)).

I did have to recompile and readd some broken references though.

But now I can compile both good code and bad code.

Comment: I would NEVER use a tool like CCleaner. What's the problem with deleting a few folders yourself? You never know for sure what these "system optimization" tools really do. I think the real solution was "readd some broken references" because I can't see any connection to the CCleaner voodoo.

Comment: Wow... Time travel :) I can't really recall what the problem was, buy I'm pretty sure CCleaner simply deleted some temp files or caching that caused the problem. I remember reading somewhere about cleaning temp files as a solution. My guess is that CCleaner handled some places I wasn't aware of.